# Tracking opened email using 1x1 pixel , is there any way to track email without gmail caching it?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

- Hi I've implement the 1x1 tracking of the email opened rates and as I go through this I learned that gmail is caching it. This was the problem of every marketer out there but I just want to know is there a new way to track opened email rates? Or is there an alternative?

HERE IS THE HTML FROM THE EMAIL RECEIVED: https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2huqsbEfNYFQ9R16WFykRzqOLnRTpzYuS_2Y0WnhO8LTHZU7BfxIaePj8I36EZBRNKfQGgmeOI_8OIbTfaImYbPfEqglWlMAP4kQkDmX94oiFOD3vClBcRr18ncMk0CsJ76xJMtEV3WXpYMFzvTieXvkoooN58KKZG1LmXF7BmZtQh3OLK5k5UxotlJNfxrSdcp-Z6MSfVtVM9nVR2xR94CARDN76IP-=s0-d-e1-ft#https://0657-180-190-130-127.ngrok-free.app/tracking?recipientEmail=juandfueajkdfl1999@gmail.com&trackingToken=63f0d2df-ed4f-4815-bbf7-b6069466b9a0

Proof that the gmail is caching it.

May i know the latest api's that I can use to track email analytics?

Thank you! Btw I'm developing it on .net core